# I am unable to insert a record into my table created in oracle database. What mistake am I doing?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
    import java.sql.*;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver;
class Jdbc1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JdbcOdbcDriver jd=new JdbcOdbcDriver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(jd);
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sai123","SYSTEM","sai123");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int res=st.executeUpdate("insert into A1 values('1','tomato','10')");
        System.out.println(res+"record is inserted..");
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

and I have creates the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE A1(
INO INTEGER NOT NULL,
INAME CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
IPRICE INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

When I compile and run the java prog it says "1 record inserted.." but when I open my table in SQLdeveloper I dont find any updates in the table. They are all null!
I have also set the classpath for ojdbc-6.jar. What mistake am I doing herE? Are there any other files that I should copy and paste? I am just a beginner so kindly please help.
And how does my program in the Editplus direct the updates directly into the table created in SQL. What path does it follow?

Comment: Please don't create tables in the `SYS`  or `SYSTEM` account...

Comment: but that is how I can connect to the oracle database isnt it?

Comment: Don't put single quote marks around integers in your INSERT statement.

Comment: You can, but you should only do admin stuff as `SYSTEM` (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT88803), and especially don't create tables there. It's very difficult to get rid of the space you requested for your test tables. Do you need instructions how to create a user?

Comment: yeah that'd surely help..please tell me how!

Comment: It's easy, use SQLDeveloper, connect as SYS or SYSTEM or DBA and run: `CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY mypassword DEFAULT TABLESPACE users  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;`. Add privs to the user as requested, for starters: `GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE TRIGGER TO myuser;` Enjoy!

Comment: Any reason you are not using the Oracle JDBC driver? Also are you sure that the ODBC DSN is actually pointing to the right database?

Comment: yes its point to the right one! I have created the dsn explicitly for this purpose!

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has auto-commit set to false by default. Either set autocommit to true from Oracle Sql Developer (or code) or commit your changes from code:

```
//before con.close()
con.commit();
```

Or if you want to set to auto-commit:

```
//after creating Connection
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: Ive added that..its still the same .

Comment: The second way is just commit transaction after `executeUpdate()`. This is done by `conn.commit()`

Comment: @SaiKrishna if it works, please consider accepting the answer, you and m3th0dman will get reputation points :-)

Comment: What does SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE table_name='A1' say in SQLDeveloper?

Comment: So there are many different tables with the name 'A1' in your database. Maybe you insert into one of them and look at another one, as @Sourav suggests. Look at the user 'SYSTEM', and it's table 'A1', this is the one you use in your Java example...

Comment: A JDBC connection is - by specification - required to start with autocommit enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try committing  the Record by calling 
`conn.commit();`

also refer the [Why Execute Update Says, one row updated on insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945754/why-does-executeupdate-return-1-even-if-no-new-row-has-been-inserted)

the final code for main should look like 

`public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {

    JdbcOdbcDriver jd=new JdbcOdbcDriver();

    DriverManager.registerDriver(jd);

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sai123","SYSTEM","sai123");

    Statement st=con.createStatement();

    int res=st.executeUpdate("insert into A1 values('1','tomato','10')");

    System.out.println(res+"record is inserted..");

    con.commit();

        st.close();

        con.close();

    }`

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the correct table under correct schema and server ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Java code and SQLDeveloper are referring to different schema? I would suggest to do the following

1. Make INO the Primary Key of the table
2. Put `con.commit();` between 
   `int res=st.executeUpdate("insert into A1 values('1','tomato','10')");`
   and
   `System.out.println(res+"record is inserted..");`
3. Run the program multiple times to check if you are getting Primary Key violation exception. This will tell you if your program is inserting to a table you are not looking at.

Comment: And how does my program in the Editplus direct the updates directly into the table created in SQL. What path does it follow?