# Update to MySQL returns 1, no errors/exception, but no updates actually take place

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

The below method is supposed to update MySql DB with the company info passed to it.

I have other methods that insert and delete and work fine, however this method runs without exceptions, and always returns 1.

The general_log file shows that it received the update string but there are still no changes.

The only time I can get it to work is if I run the code in the MySql workplace directly.

If you need more info to figure this out, please let me know. 
I gave you all I thought was needed.
Thanks.

```
// SQL update string received from the program in the log file
//  UPDATE couponsprojectdb.company SET Email = 'admin@MyCompany.org', Password = 'pass' WHERE ID = 3


public void updateCompanyById(Company c, long id) throws SQLException 
{
        Connection conn = pool.getConnection(); // Gets an available connection from pool
        // Prepared statement string
        String sql = ("UPDATE company SET Email = ?, Password = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        p.setString(1, c.getEmail());
        p.setString(2, c.getPassword());
        p.setLong(3, id);
        int i = p.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("changes: " + i);
        pool.releaseConnection(conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called `conn.commit()` after doing the `executeUpdate()`.  The reason the Java code returns `1` is because it succeeded, but the database rolled back the `UPDATE` immediately after the transaction ended.

You also need to close your connections.  Change your code to this:

```
try {
    Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
    String sql = ("UPDATE company SET Email = ?, Password = ? WHERE ID = ?");
    PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    p.setString(1, c.getEmail());
    p.setString(2, c.getPassword());
    p.setLong(3, id);
    int i = p.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();      // <-- MAKE SURE TO COMMIT THE TRANSACTION TO THE DATABASE!!!
    System.out.println("changes: " + i);
    pool.releaseConnection(conn);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle errors here
} finally {
    try { if (p != null) p.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    try { if (conn != null) pool.releaseConnection(conn); } catch (Exception e) {};
}
```

Big hat tip to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945754/why-does-executeupdate-return-1-even-if-no-new-row-has-been-inserted) which got me thinking about your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. conn.commit() did the trick. However I'm not sure why I had to do that because I didn't change the autoCommit in this method.

Comment: Another question on your answer. I threw an exception and didn't try,catch,finally and pool.releaseconnection (I know I need to do that) but why do I need to p.close()?  #1 once I release the connection doesn't that do it for me? #2 as soon as the method is completed its ready for garbage collection and will then be closed??

Comment: One more thing. If it returns 1 because it succeeded. If I run the same code again, (After it already made the update) it still returns 1. How can I get 0 or some other info if it didn't update the row, or the row does not exist?

Comment: To your first question: It is considered good practice to close the `ResultSet`, `Statement`, and `Connection` separately, in that order, because if one fails to close, you want to still have a chance to close the others.

Comment: To your second question: It returns 1 upon doing the same `UPDATE` because the database performed the same update operation again.  That the row hasn't changed doesn't matter because the `UPDATE` took place.  It should return 0 if you specify a condition in your `WHERE` clause which fails (and please try this now).

Comment: `UPDATE couponsprojectdb.company SET Email = 'info@MyCompany.org', Password = 'pass' WHERE (ID = 3
AND Email != 'info@MyCompany.org' AND Password != 'pass')`. This works. but i want the second and do be an if. (the id must match, but the change should only ocure if either email or password dont match) `IF (Email != x || Password != y)`